# Form filters failing fast and furious

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba, dao, ms-access-2013

As a precursor, I am a newbie to Access and Stackoverflow, so any errors in context, statements, verbiage, etc., are purely unintentional. I have a good heart, good intentions, and mean no offense.

I have 5 forms in my unsplit, DAO 2013 Access db that all use identical coding regarding this specific issue. On opening, all forms are set to open to a new, blank record.

When a customer record is searched and the record is opened, all forms have a subform container which is tabbed and contains the bulk of the customer's record information.

On 1 of these forms, the navigation bar states "no filter" and shows the customer's record information in the subform container. Regardless of the filter state, the customer record information should show, so this is what should happen.

On 4 of these forms, the form navigation bar states "Unfiltered" and displays none of the customer's record information in the subform container. If I click the filter button on the bottom of the form (or the filter toggle in the ribbon) twice the customer record information will display on the second click - and the form moves to "Filtered" and then again "Unfiltered". All Subforms then behave normally in the second "Unfiltered" state.

There are -0- manual VBA filters (i.e., `me.customer.filter = false`) currently set in my db, -0- queries used to find records - everything is built using VBA to locate records.

End users will not be able to use the filter controls once the db goes live. This is my final bug. I appreciate any suggestions or solutions that may be offered.

These are the solutions I have attempted:

- used `Me.FilterOn = False` and `Me.Filter = ""` to turn off all filters on the 4 affected forms on opening, but this caused the filter toggle to become unavailable and the subform container to not display any customer record information on the 4 forms
- used `Me.FilterOn = False` and `Me.Filter = ""` to turn off all filters on the 4 affected forms on current, but this caused the filter toggle to become unavailable and the subform container to not display any customer record information on the 4 forms
- used VBA above to turn off all filters on all 5 forms on opening, this caused the filter toggle to become unavailable and the subform container to not display any customer record information on all 5 forms
- decompiled, repaired/compressed, and rebuilt into a new db a couple of times
- using VBA to force the unfiltered/filtered/unfiltered state to occur on opening, but subforms interfered and my deadline doesn't leave me time to figure it out.
- attempting to base everything off queries instead of tables, but as these subforms must be editable and the queries must be unique, this was not an option
- compared the one form against the others to see what is different vs. what is the same on opening/searching. in this, they are identical.

As a final wrap up, if anyone would like to look at my setup, just let me know, I have a stripped down version ready. I did not post any code here as I'm not sure what you'll want to look at.

Thank you again,

Trapper

Comment: Since I don't know what launches these forms (all at once?), or how you navigate to any given record, or if you properly linked the child and parent forms, or what other code is involved... did you try a subform refresh when the record is selected? This is not the way to go... do you have proper links?

Comment: The child & parent forms are properly linked, The forms do not open together, they disseminate one form per user type of user after login, i.e., Analyst will use Analyst form, Salesman will use Sales form. I agree, it is not the way to go, so no, I am not requesting a subform refresh when a record is selected. My links function: they pull up the correct record, fields display the correct dropdowns, etc. I know it has to do with the filter trigger, I've used every troubleshooting tool I've had pointed at me & I'm just out of ideas & research.

Comment: I'll be happy to put them up. How/where would you like me to do this?

Comment: Here you go. User table has the login info. "Sales" form is functional, the "Analyst", "Engineer", "Operations", "HelpDesk" pages are the pages that are failing to function correctly on initial open. If you attempt to open the form without logging in you will receive an error, unless you are in design mode. Feel free to make any changes you wish, I have a backed up copy. Thank you again, sir!   https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mb8mp32xvpw4iy/HotelTest.accdb?dl=0

Comment: Well, I've got to admit that I'm stumped... so far... I believe I have a workaround. Since subform 'SFSiteAnalyst' is the problem, and it looks to be the same as 'SFSiteSales', make a backup copy of the 'bad' subform, then clone SFSiteSales and rename as SFSiteAnalyst. I hav tried opening that subform by itself, deleting all controls, adding back; compact & repair, etc. but no luck...yet...  I also extracted every control and every property for all objects and did a quick compare without seeing a glaring difference (over 3600 properties!)  Will try a few more things tomorrow!

Comment: I went ahead and did as you suggest in the workaround, all is well and working. If you want to go ahead and put that up as an answer, I'll take it. If you want to keep working towards finding the ultimate solution, you are welcome to do so. But you found resolution to the craziness, and I'm extremely grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found the cause of your problem.

Form 'sfSiteAnalyst' has the property 'Data Entry' set to Yes. Change to No and it works just fine.

Just comparing the 3,889 properties for that form and controls led to finding 58 that were different -- but the other differences were meaningless (top, border, etc.)

Also, I notice there are many places where you issue a 'DoCmd.Save acForm, ...' that caused me problems with testing. Are they really necessary?

Comment: If I change Data Entry to no, won't that cause issues with other properties of the form/subform not allowing data entry or changes to the existing records? Regarding the `doCmd.Save acForm` I'd like to remove them, but when I try it cascades issues. My boss is paranoid about saving records. I noticed during testing some records auto-saved. Is there a resource you know of that provides the rules regarding Access auto-saves specifically, so I can learn appropriate use of the save command structure?

Comment: Re Data Entry, setting to Yes means no records displayed... See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DataEntry-Property-f4236759-27f6-4fcd-abb0-4aa4acd8fe87 
Re DoCmd.Save acForm, that is not the way to save a changed record. Use either DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord, or If Me.Dirty Then
  Me.Dirty = False
End If
Changed records save automatically when moving to another record. In som applications, I prefer to have code that checks to see if Dirty, then prompt user to ask if they want to save (i.e. user bouncing around on a form and accidentally chances a value)

Comment: Thank you again, Wayne. I guess my common-sense thinking, uh, wasn't. I've removed as many of the `DoCmd.Save acForm` statements as possible and switched to the `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False` instead where appropriate. If you're willing to take this one step further, I have one other issue - form lockup on save - that has come up as a result of that change. However, under forum rules, it should rightfully be dealt with in a different question. Would you be willing to help on that, since you're now familiar with the db? I'll repost in a different question. Thank you again for the learning!